# Need to get an Iterator for an RDD for a partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm looking for a way to get an `Iterator[]` from a given RDD or DataFrame not through the `map()` or `mapPartition()` since I want to take this iterator and along with another one from another RDD do something else.

Example:

```
(0 until partitionCount).foreach(i => {
  val iter1 = leftRdd.getIteratorForPartition(i)
  val iter2 = rightRdd.getIteratorForPartition(i)
  resultPartitions += CustomCombine(keys, iter1, iter2)
})

// and create an RDD for DataFrame from resultPartitions
```

So basically I'm looking for the equivalent of my made up function: **getIteratorForPartition()**

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Wouldn't it make more sense to use a `join` or something similar?

Comment: This is to do the join but not using Spark's join logic

Comment: Apparently there is an RDD.iterator() function which returns what i want however the comments in code mentions that this is not meant to be called by users. Does anyone know why?